# Float Decimal Point Display Setting in Polars

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way to adjust or change a setting that Polars would show a same number of decimal points for all values?

And if it is, am I able to save it as default for all new notebooks in Jupyter for instance?

For example,

```
pl.DataFrame({"a":[0.1213, 0.4244, 0.1000, 0.4242]})
```

Output:
shape: (4, 1)

```
┌────────┐
│ a      │
│ ---    │
│ f64    │
╞════════╡
│ 0.1213 │
│ 0.4244 │
│ 0.1    │
│ 0.4242 │
└────────┘
```

I'd like to see the 0.1 as 0.1000

Answer (score 3):

This feature was added by [#7475](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7475) in October 2023. As of Polars v0.20.2 you can do the following:

```py
with pl.Config(set_float_precision=4):
    print(pl.DataFrame({"a":[0.1213, 0.4244, 0.1000, 0.4242]}))
```

Output:

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌────────┐
│ a      │
│ ---    │
│ f64    │
╞════════╡
│ 0.1213 │
│ 0.4244 │
│ 0.1000 │
│ 0.4242 │
└────────┘
```

See the [config docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think right now we do not have this kind of options on the Polars API

If you take a look at https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html

We only have limited options to format tables and strings.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your questions, but if the intention is just to print values to the same number of decimal points:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"a":[0.1213, 0.4244, 0.1000, 0.4242]})

(
    df.lazy()
    .with_column(
        pl.col("a").round(4).cast(pl.Utf8).str.split(".")
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col("a").arr.first().arr
        .concat(
            pl.col("a").arr.last().str.ljust(width=4, fillchar="0")
        ).arr.join(".")
    )
    .collect()
)
```